# biased prediction on output variable

Tags: regression, linear-model

Consider the linear regression model, 
$y = Xβ + \varepsilon$, 
where as usual $y$ and $\varepsilon$ are of dimension $n × 1$, $X$ is $n × k$ and $β$ is $k × 1$. Additionally, 
the error term is correlated with the data such that $E(\varepsilon|X) = γ$ column vector not equal to zero. Let
the corresponding OLS estimator be $\hat{β} = ((X′X)^{-1})(X′y)$. Assume conditionality on $X$.

I have solved all the other parts of the question. But I am not able to understand what does the below question mean and how I show the proof .
Q. Does this regression model produces biased predictions of the outcome variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Predictions are $\hat{y}=X\hat{\beta}$; and $$\begin{align}E[\hat{y}|X]&=E[X\hat{\beta}|X]=E[X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T(X\beta+\epsilon)|X]\\&=E[X\beta+X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T\epsilon|X]\\&=X\beta+\underbrace{X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T}_{A}E[\epsilon|X]\\&=X\beta+A\gamma\end{align}$$
Normally, you should have $X\beta$ only, given the data, i.e. you should be expecting your calculated outcome to be the outcome calculated with the true parameters, $\beta$, however the right term, $A\gamma$, is an additional term that lead to bias.